# fabricJS Not persisting Floodfill

Tags: fabricjs

I have an algorithm for Floodfilling a canvas. Im trying to incorporate this with fabricJS. So here is the dilemna.... I create a fabric.Canvas(). Which creates a wrapper canvas and also an upper-canvas canvas. I click on the canvas to apply my Floodfill(). This works fine and applies my color. But as soon as i go to drag my canvas objects around, or add additional objects to the canvas, the color disappears and looks like it resets of sort.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: would love some example code to run. hard to tell what is happening with what you describe here.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because fabricjs wipe out all canvas every frame and redraw from its internal data.

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSfiddle that implements Flood Fill for Fabric JS. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/av01d/dfvp9j2u/

```
/*
 * FloodFill for fabric.js
 * @author Arjan Haverkamp (av01d)
 * @date October 2018
 */

 var FloodFill = {

    // Compare subsection of array1's values to array2's values, with an optional tolerance
    withinTolerance: function(array1, offset, array2, tolerance)
    {
        var length = array2.length,
            start = offset + length;
        tolerance = tolerance || 0;

        // Iterate (in reverse) the items being compared in each array, checking their values are
        // within tolerance of each other
        while(start-- && length--) {
            if(Math.abs(array1[start] - array2[length]) > tolerance) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    },

    // The actual flood fill implementation
    fill: function(imageData, getPointOffsetFn, point, color, target, tolerance, width, height)
    {
        var directions = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1], [-1, 0]],
            coords = [],
            points = [point],
            seen = {},
            key,
            x,
            y,
            offset,
            i,
            x2,
            y2,
            minX = -1,
            maxX = -1,
            minY = -1,
            maxY = -1;

        // Keep going while we have points to walk
        while (!!(point = points.pop())) {
            x = point.x;
            y = point.y;
            offset = getPointOffsetFn(x, y);

            // Move to next point if this pixel isn't within tolerance of the color being filled
            if (!FloodFill.withinTolerance(imageData, offset, target, tolerance)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (x > maxX) { maxX = x; }
            if (y > maxY) { maxY = y; }
            if (x < minX || minX == -1) { minX = x; }
            if (y < minY || minY == -1) { minY = y; }

            // Update the pixel to the fill color and add neighbours onto stack to traverse
            // the fill area
            i = directions.length;
            while (i--) {
                // Use the same loop for setting RGBA as for checking the neighbouring pixels
                if (i < 4) {
                    imageData[offset + i] = color[i];
                    coords[offset+i] = color[i];
                }

                // Get the new coordinate by adjusting x and y based on current step
                x2 = x + directions[i][0];
                y2 = y + directions[i][1];
                key = x2 + ',' + y2;

                // If new coordinate is out of bounds, or we've already added it, then skip to
                // trying the next neighbour without adding this one
                if (x2 < 0 || y2 < 0 || x2 >= width || y2 >= height || seen[key]) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Push neighbour onto points array to be processed, and tag as seen
                points.push({ x: x2, y: y2 });
                seen[key] = true;
            }
        }

        return {
            x: minX,
            y: minY,
            width: maxX-minX,
            height: maxY-minY,
            coords: coords
        }
    }

}; // End FloodFill


var fcanvas; // Fabric Canvas
var fillColor = '#f00';
var fillTolerance = 2;

function hexToRgb(hex, opacity) {
    opacity = Math.round(opacity * 255) || 255;
    hex = hex.replace('#', '');
    var rgb = [], re = new RegExp('(.{' + hex.length/3 + '})', 'g');
    hex.match(re).map(function(l) {
        rgb.push(parseInt(hex.length % 2 ? l+l : l, 16));
    });
    return rgb.concat(opacity);
}

function floodFill(enable) {
    if (!enable) {
        fcanvas.off('mouse:down');
        fcanvas.selection = true;
        fcanvas.forEachObject(function(object){
            object.selectable = true;
        });
        return;
    }

    fcanvas.deactivateAll().renderAll(); // Hide object handles!
    fcanvas.selection = false;
    fcanvas.forEachObject(function(object){
        object.selectable = false;
    });

    fcanvas.on({
        'mouse:down': function(e) {
            var mouse = fcanvas.getPointer(e.e),
                mouseX = Math.round(mouse.x), mouseY = Math.round(mouse.y),
                canvas = fcanvas.lowerCanvasEl,
                context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                parsedColor = hexToRgb(fillColor),
                imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
                getPointOffset = function(x,y) {
                    return 4 * (y * imageData.width + x)
                },
                targetOffset = getPointOffset(mouseX, mouseY),
                target = imageData.data.slice(targetOffset, targetOffset + 4);

            if (FloodFill.withinTolerance(target, 0, parsedColor, fillTolerance)) {
                // Trying to fill something which is (essentially) the fill color
                console.log('Ignore... same color')
                return;
            }

            // Perform flood fill
            var data = FloodFill.fill(
                imageData.data,
                getPointOffset,
                { x: mouseX, y: mouseY },
                parsedColor,
                target,
                fillTolerance,
                imageData.width,
                imageData.height
            );

            if (0 == data.width || 0 == data.height) {
                return;
            }

            var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'), tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
            tmpCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            tmpCanvas.height = canvas.height;

            var palette = tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, tmpCanvas.width, tmpCanvas.height); // x, y, w, h
            palette.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(data.coords)); // Assuming values 0..255, RGBA
            tmpCtx.putImageData(palette, 0, 0); // Repost the data.
            var imgData = tmpCtx.getImageData(data.x, data.y, data.width, data.height); // Get cropped image

            tmpCanvas.width = data.width;
            tmpCanvas.height = data.height;
            tmpCtx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);

            fcanvas.add(new fabric.Image(tmpCanvas, {
                left: data.x,
                top: data.y,
        selectable: false
            }))
        }
    });
}

$(function() {

  // Init Fabric Canvas:
    fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        enableRetinaScaling: false
    });

    // Add some demo-shapes:
    fcanvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 80,
        fill: false,
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 2
    }));
    fcanvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
        width: 120,
        height: 160,
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        stroke: '#000',
        fill: '#00f',
        strokeWidth: 2
    }));
    fcanvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        width: 120,
        height: 160,
        left: 150,
        top: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 2
    }));
    fcanvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        width: 200,
        height: 120,
        left: 200,
        top: 120,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 2
    }));

  /* Images work very well too. Make sure they're CORS
     enabled though! */
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
        fcanvas.add(new fabric.Image(img, {
            left: 300,
            top: 100,
            angle: 30,
        }));  
  }
    img.src = 'http://misc.avoid.org/chip.png';
});
```